# MongoDB.Drive falha ao filtrar com ElemMatch um Array de objeto

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-core

Tenho um Document no mongoDB com essa formação:

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(21),
    "_t" : "Detail",
    "DeletionDate" : null,
    "CreationDate" : null,
    "UpdateDate" : null,
    "Accounts" : [ 
        {
            "Bank" : "123",
            "BankAccount" : "123456"
        }
    ]
}
```

e estou tentando fazer uma consulta filtrando pela propriedade Bank dentro de Accounts
minhas classes são:
**Atualizada em 06/08/2020**
**IDetail.cs**

```
public Interface IDetails
{

     long? Id { get; set; }
     
     DateTime? DeletionDate { get; set; }

     DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }

     DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }
     
     List<SpecificAccount> Accounts;

}
```

**Detail.cs**

```
[BsonDiscriminator("Details")]
public class Details : IDetails
{

     public virtual long? Id { get; set; }

     [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc)]
     public DateTime? DeletionDate { get; set; }

     [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc)]
     public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }

     [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc)]
     public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }
     
     private List<SpecificAccount> _accounts;

     public List<SpecificAccount> Accounts {
         get
         {
             if (_accounts == null)
                 return new List<SpecificAccount>();
             return _accounts;
         }
         set { _accounts = value;  } 
     }

}
```

**SpecificAccount.cs**

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class SpecificAccount
{
    public string Bank { get; set; }

    public string BankAccount { get; set; }
}
```

e a consulta está sendo feita dessa maneira:

```
...
var filter = Builders<IDetails>.Filter.And( Builders<IDetails>.Filter.Eq("_id", id) );

if (bank != null)
    filter &= Builders<IDetails>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Accounts, y => y.Bank.Equals(bank));

return Collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
```

mas estou obtendo uma exceção ao rodar o código em tempo de execução:

**Message:
Test method Tests.AccountServiceTests.TestShouldGetAccount threw exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the serialization information for x => x.Accounts.**

**Stack Trace:
ExpressionFieldDefinition`1.Render(IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
ElementMatchFilterDefinition`2.Render(IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
AndFilterDefinition`1.Render(IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
MongoCollectionImpl`1.CreateFindOperation[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options) MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindSync[TProjection](IClientSessionHandle session, FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
<>c__DisplayClass41_0`1.<FindSync>b__0(IClientSessionHandle session) MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSession[TResult](Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken) MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindSync[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
FindFluent`2.ToCursor(CancellationToken cancellationToken) IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.FirstOrDefault[TDocument](IAsyncCursorSource`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
IFindFluentExtensions.FirstOrDefault[TDocument,TProjection](IFindFluent`2 find, CancellationToken cancellationToken)**

Até achei que podia ser algo no **registerClassMap** mas não adiantou

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Details>(cm => {
           cm.MapProperty(c => c.Accounts);
});
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: direto no mongo seria: **db.getCollection('Detail').find({ Accounts: { $elemMatch: {"Bank" : "123"}} })**

Comment: Bem provável que é por causa daquele _getter_.

Comment: Eu havia esquecido de adicionar a interface IDetail mas no Find estava usando ela. quando removi essa interface e usei somente a classe resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de várias tentativas e erros, descobri que quando removia  a interface IDetail.cs do Find e passava a utilizar a Classe Detail.cs a consulta funcionava. ficando a consulta dessa maneira:

```
...
var filter = Builders<Details>.Filter.And( Builders<Details>.Filter.Eq("_id", id) );

if (bank != null)
    filter &= Builders<Details>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Accounts, y => y.Bank.Equals(bank));

return Collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
```